# Is there a Teradata equivalent to R’s rbind?

Tags: sql, r, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I’m trying to combine table1 (with columns “id”, “state”, “cost”) and table2 (with same columns “id”, “state”, “cost”) such that all rows are combined into a single table3. There may be duplicates for “id” and/or “state” but all duplicates should be retained.

Table1:

| Id | State | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IL | 50 |
| 3 | CA | 10 |
| 2 | WY | 70 |

Table2:

| Id | State | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | NY | 100 |
| 3 | PA | 15 |
| 6 | FL | 5 |

Goal table3:

| Id | State | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IL | 50 |
| 3 | CA | 10 |
| 2 | WY | 70 |
| 4 | NY | 100 |
| 3 | PA | 15 |
| 6 | FL | 5 |

This would be a simple rbind using R but I’m probably overthinking it in Teradata.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you need to look up the various `union` commands.

Comment: Yup, you want `select Id, State, Cost from table1 UNION ALL select Id, State, Cost from table2`

Comment: I'm not a teradata user by any means, but because *"Teradata Database conforms closely to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard"* ([ref](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-Introduction/June-2017/Database-Objects-Databases-and-Users/For-More-Information)), it may help you to expand your research to include SQL (without "teradata"). This is not a criticism of the question, it's a suggestion to help improve research mechanisms so that you don't have to ask here and wait for others to reply :-)